# GET and filter_input stops at the "#" symbol

Tags: php, get, filter-input

I have the following url

```
http://www.example.com/check.php?q=498#2D83B631%3800EBD!801600D*7E3CC13
```

Then I try

```
<?php var_dump( $_GET); ?>
```

and

```
<?php
echo $my_string = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'q', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
?>
```

But they both seem to stop at the "#" symbol and only display `498`. Is there a way to retrieve the entire `498#2D83B631%3800EBD!801600D*7E3CC13`?

Comment: Yes, because `#` in a URL defines where the `fragment` section begins, ending the query part. You need to encode special characters.

Answer (score 1):

On the server you can get only the url until `#`. If you want the value after `#` you need some client side script to get the url.

If that is value of `q` you should encode first with `urlencode()`. In this way you will get all the value from `q`

Your url should look like: http://www.example.com/check.php?q=498%232D83B631%253800EBD!801600D*7E3CC13

To decode the url you can use `urldecode()`

Answer (score 0):

Fragments are not send to the server at all.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier

> When an agent (such as a Web browser) requests a web resource from a Web server, > the agent sends the URI to the server, but does not send the fragment.

Passing the data as another GET parameter would be a viable alternative.